# Вставка в базу H2 c помощью hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Вылетает ошибка при попытке выполнить запрос к базе.
Соедиение с базой проходит без исключений
Установкой фабрики сессий, и выполнением запросов занимается класс:

```
public class DBService {
    private static final String hibernate_show_sql = "true";
    private static final String hibernate_hbm2ddl_auto = "Update";

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public DBService() {
        Configuration configuration = getH2Configuration();
        sessionFactory = createSessionFactory(configuration);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")


    private Configuration getH2Configuration() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(UsersDataSet.class);

        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.h2.Driver");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:h2:~/test");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "sa");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "sa");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", hibernate_show_sql);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hibernate_hbm2ddl_auto);

        return configuration;
    }


    public UsersDataSet getUser(long id) throws DBException {
        try {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            UsersDAO dao = new UsersDAO(session);
            UsersDataSet dataSet = dao.get(id);
            session.close();
            return dataSet;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw new DBException(e);
        }
    }
    public UsersDataSet getUser(String  login) throws DBException {
        try {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            UsersDAO dao = new UsersDAO(session);
            Long id  = dao.getUserId(login);
            UsersDataSet dataSet = dao.get(id);
            session.close();
             return dataSet;
        } catch (NullPointerException q) {
            throw q;

        }catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw new DBException(e);
        }
    }

    public long addUser(String login,String password) throws DBException {
        try {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            UsersDAO dao = new UsersDAO(session);
            long id = dao.insertUser(login,password);
            transaction.commit();
            session.close();
            return id;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw new DBException(e);
        }
    }

    public void printConnectInfo() {
        try {
            SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactoryImpl = (SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory;
            Connection connection = sessionFactoryImpl.getConnectionProvider().getConnection();
            System.out.println("DB name: " + connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());
            System.out.println("DB version: " + connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductVersion());
            System.out.println("Driver: " + connection.getMetaData().getDriverName());
            System.out.println("Autocommit: " + connection.getAutoCommit());

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    private static SessionFactory createSessionFactory(Configuration configuration) {
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        builder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = builder.build();
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
}
```

Далее На обьекте `DBService` вызываю метод `addUser("User", "pass" )`, в теле которого вызывается `insertUser("User", "pass" )` объекта UserDao

DBService :

```
public long addUser(String login,String password) throws DBException {
        try {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            UsersDAO dao = new UsersDAO(session);
            long id = dao.insertUser(login,password);
            transaction.commit();
            session.close();
            return id;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw new DBException(e);
        }
    }
```

UsersDao:

```
 public long insertUser(String login, String password) throws HibernateException {
        return (Long) session.save(new UsersDataSet(login,password));
}
```

Класc UseresDataSet

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UsersDataSet  implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8706689714326132798L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "login", unique = true, updatable = false)
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "psaword",  updatable = false)
    private String pasword;


    //Important to Hibernate!
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public UsersDataSet() {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public UsersDataSet(long id, String login) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setPasword(login);
    }

    public UsersDataSet(String login, String pasword) {
         this.setId(-1);
        this.setlogin(login);
        this.setPasword(pasword);

    }

    public void setlogin(String login) {
        this.login=login;
    }
    public void setPasword(String pasword) {
        this.pasword = pasword;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserDataSet{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", login='" + login + "password= "+ pasword+ '\'' +
                '}';
    }

}
```

в стектрейсе пишет что изначально  Exception летит из `insertUser`

```
 січ. 18, 2016 4:27:37 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02
січ. 18, 2016 4:27:37 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Таблица "USERS" не найдена
Table "USERS" not found; SQL statement:
insert into users (id, login, pasword) values (null, ?, ?) [42102-187]
dbService.DBException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at dbService.DBService.addUser(DBService.java:125)
    at servlets.SignUpServlet.doPost(SignUpServlet.java:42)
```

**UPD.**
При использовании  Postgres

```
 Configuration configuration = getPostgresConfiguration;
   sessionFactory = createSessionFactory(configuration);
```

все выполняется успешно

pom. xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>L2.1</groupId>
    <artifactId>L2.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
                    <finalName>server</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <properties>
        <com.h2database.h2.version>1.4.187</com.h2database.h2.version>
        <mysql.mysql-connector-java.version>5.1.35</mysql.mysql-connector-java.version>
        <org.hibernate.hibernate-core.version>4.3.10.Final</org.hibernate.hibernate-core.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.M0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.M0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>${com.h2database.h2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.hibernate-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>





    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

нашел ошибку в строке  `private static final String hibernate_hbm2ddl_auto = "Update";` надо `'update'`